# Is there a better way to write this code? (Finding lowest number AND greatest number in array) [Java]

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, search

So I have this piece of code which basically is trying to find the largest number in an array and the smallest number (here it's ticket price). But I find myself writing two for loops, I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to write this?

```
    /** Setting cheapestCost to the index of the cheapest transport obj*/
    for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        if(allTransports[cheapestCost].getTicketPrice() > allTransports[i].getTicketPrice()) {
            cheapestCost = i;
        }
    }
        
    /** Setting greatestCost to the index of the most expensive transport obj*/
    for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        if(allTransports[greatestCost].getTicketPrice() < allTransports[i].getTicketPrice()) {
            greatestCost = i;
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just do both operations in the same loop?   Both loops iterate over the same range, and the two operations don't interact with each other, so there's nothing standing in the way of combining the two loops into one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems to me you can just combine those two loops:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    int price = allTransports[i].getTicketPrice();

    if(allTransports[cheapestCost].getTicketPrice() > price) {
        cheapestCost = i;
    }

    if(allTransports[greatestCost].getTicketPrice() < price) {
        greatestCost = i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont use array sort ?

```
Int[] Tickets = new int[TicketsPrice.length]
For(int i =0;i < Tickets.length ; i++){
Tickets[i] = TicketsPrice.getPrice();
}
Int[] Arr = Arrays.sort(Tickets)
Arr[0] \\ => smallest number
Arr[Arr.length -1] \\=> largest number
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick that reduces the number of comparisons you have to do. Divide the array into pairs, and make a comparison in each pair. The higher number in the pair is a candidate for highest element, so make one compare there. The lower number in the pair is a candidate for lowest element, so make one compare there. This costs you three compares per two numbers, whereas the straightforward way costs you two compares per number or four compares per two numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Whether it’s any better is a matter of taste. You may use a stream operation:

```
    /** Setting cheapestCost to the index of the cheapest transport obj*/
    int cheapestCost = IntStream.range(0, 15)
            .boxed()
            .min(Comparator.comparing(i -> allTransports[i].getTicketPrice()))
            .orElseThrow();
```

Similarly for the most expensive transport ticket, just use `max()` instead of `min()`.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way, you should sort the array by ascending of ticket price then get the first and last element.
But do not change the original order of the array, just store the sorted array in a new variable.

```
Transport[] allTransports = {new Transport(), new Transport()};
List<Integer> naturalSortedPrices =
Arrays.stream(allTransports).map(Transport::getTicketPrice).sorted()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

int cheapestCost = naturalSortedPrices.get(0);
int greatestCost = naturalSortedPrices.get(naturalSortedPrices.size() - 1);
```